# Unique Instances By Two Groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I'm trying to determine the number of unique customers per week per store.

I have a piece of code that accomplishes this task but the tabulation is not what I am looking for.

I have the following table:

```
store   week    customer_ID
1          1    1
1          1    1
1          1    2
1          2    1
1          2    2
1          2    3
2          1    1
2          1    1
2          1    2
2          2    2
2          2    3
2          2    3
```

So every week I need to count how many unique customer there were.

Say for example if customer 1 had visited on week 1, then revisited on week 2 that would not count as a unique visit.

If that same customer visited store 2 on week 1 or any other week. Then that would count as a unique visit for store two.

The outcome would look like the following:

```
store   week    unique Customers
1           1   2
1           2   1
2           1   2
2           2   1
```

I used the following but its not correct

```
agg <-  aggregate(data=df, customer_ID~ week+store, function(x) length(unique(x)))

structure(list(store = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), week = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), customer_ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("store", "week", "customer_ID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R method. The idea is to split the data into a list of data.frames, one for each store. Assuming observations are ordered by week, then drop duplicated observations of customer ID. The subset data.frame is aggregated using your function. Then `do.call` and `rbind` put the results into a single data.frame:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$store),
                      function(i) aggregate(data=i[!duplicated(i$customer_ID),],
                                            customer_ID ~ week+store, length)))
    week store customer_ID
1.1    1     1           2
1.2    2     1           1
2.1    1     2           2
2.2    2     2           1
```

to make sure that your data.frame is ordered properly prior to attempting this, you could use `order`:

```
df <- df[order(df$store, df$week), ]
```

---

In case it is of interest, I put together a `data.table` solution as well.

library(data.table)
setDT(df)

```
df[df[, !duplicated(customer_ID), by=store]$V1, 
   .(newCust=length(customer_ID)), by=.(store, week)]
   store week newCust
1:     1    1       2
2:     1    2       1
3:     2    1       2
4:     2    2       1
```

This method uses a logical vector `df[, !duplicated(customer_ID), by=store]$V1` to subset the data to unique IDs by store, and then calculates the unique number of new customers by store-week.

Comment: so before I run that piece of code I should arrange by week only? or by week and store?

Comment: @Imo could you include the arrangement/order function for clarity?

Comment: i was wondering if there could be a data.table/dplyr solution to this?

Comment: @joel.wilson I added one `data.table` method. I'm not sure it is the most efficient, but it gets the job done.